# How to add TXT record in Host File

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, txt-record

Is is possible to add TXT record in local hostfile for local verification ?

I was looking for this for demo purpose on a Linux server.

Answer (score 4):

The [Linux hosts file](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html) is merely an `IP -> hostname` mapping. The operating systems is not querying itself for a DNS record, nor is it responding to its own query with a DNS record. It's responding with an IP address.

If you need a local host to respond with a specific DNS record type you'll need to install and configure DNS server software.